# How can I add two spaces after each line on a given text in EMACS?

Tags: emacs, markdown

Seeking how could add two spaces after each line on a given text buffer in EMACS.

This is a way for add LINE BREAKS on EMACS export via org-mode.

Comment: You could also do this with the `multiple-cursors` package in one fell swoop, but it starts to bog down after 500 plus cursors depending upon what else is going on inside the buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, make sure you (or some package you've installed) haven't added `delete-trailing-whitespace` on a hook.  It's not on any hooks by default, but it's fairly common to add it to `before-save-hook`.

**Quick and dirty:**

`C-M-< C-M-% $ RET SPACE SPACE RET !`.

1. This will go to the beginning of the buffer (`C-M-<`),
2. start `query-replace-regexp` (`C-M-%`),
3. replacing end of line (`$`) with two spaces and
4. applying it to the every match (`!`).

Above, `RET` means press the return key and `SPACE` means press the space bar.  Replace `$` with `[^ ][^ ]$` and `SPACE SPACE` with `\& SPACE SPACE` to only work on lines that end in less than two spaces (this will also make the operation idempotent).  `\&` means the entire matched string (in this case, the last two characters).

---

**Function:**

```
(defun ensure-trailing-spaces ()  
  "Ensure there are two spaces at the end of every line."
  (interactive "*")
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (not (eobp))
      (end-of-line)
      (unless (looking-back "  $")
        (insert "  "))
      (forward-line))))
```

Note that this unconditionally inserts two spaces at the end of every line, even if there is already one space, thus there will either be two or three spaces at the end of every line.